# Dynamically adding routes that reference underlying routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am new to web APIs and my design might be plain wrong, so feel free to correct my idea. We are building a series of web APIs, and we need to implement for most of them an excel and CSV export. What I imagined was that I could list all the routes in my application, and dynamically add new routes that handle the excel/CSV conversion.

For example, if I have a route api/customers, I want my service to create a new route on its own, which will be api/customers/excel and will return the same data as an excel file. This new route will take all the arguments of the initial route plus the names of the columns to export.

Adding the routes went kinda alright (even though I did not test it extensively and I might have added bugs with my copy ?) :

```
public class CustomDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    public override IReadOnlyList<RouteEntry> GetDirectRoutes(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, IReadOnlyList<HttpActionDescriptor> actionDescriptors,
        IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)
    {
        var routes = base.GetDirectRoutes(controllerDescriptor, actionDescriptors, constraintResolver);

        var result = new List<RouteEntry>();
        foreach (var routeEntry in routes)
        {
            result.Add(routeEntry);
            var defaults = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(routeEntry.Route.Defaults.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value));
            var constraints = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(routeEntry.Route.Constraints.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value));
            var dataTokens = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(routeEntry.Route.DataTokens.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value));

            var copy = new RouteEntry(routeEntry.Name,
                new HttpRoute(
                    routeEntry.Route.RouteTemplate + "/csv",
                    defaults,
                    constraints,
                    dataTokens
                    ));
            result.Add(copy);
        }

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<RouteEntry>(result);
    }
}

public class OwinConfiguration
{
    public void Configure(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        /* lots of stuff */

        var inlineConstraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
        var directRouteProvider = new CustomDirectRouteProvider();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(inlineConstraintResolver, directRouteProvider);
    }
}
```

What I would like to do now is to use the underlying handler for the newly created routes, and then call my conversion method :

```
return response.AsCsvExport(columnHeaders);
```

on the HttpResponseMessage. For now, the route copy does the same thing as the reference route. If I try to add a handler in the HttpRoute constructor :

```
public class CsvExportDelegatingHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var route = request.GetRouteData().Route.RouteTemplate;
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response.AsCsvExport();
    }
}

var handler = HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpControllerDispatcher(Configuration), new DelegatingHandler[] { new CsvExportDelegatingHandler() });
```

my app fails to initialize. Is there any way to do that?
Our service is built with WepApi 2, Owin and Autofac if that matters.

Comment: I think what you want is [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for since this will force all the future routes to declare the /excel or /csv themselves, and require the parameter with the column names. Ideally I would have wanted to do that automatically.